# Difference between React-Native-fcm and React-Native-Firebase dependency

Tags: firebase, react-native

Why we use these two different lib's if the moto of those is same?

[Not able to run React-Native by following this to build FCM notifications in React-Native-App](https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm)

Please help and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you interested in only FCM then you can use react-native-fcm but if you interested in other firebase serve like firestore , analytics , storage then you should use react-native-firebase

Comment: Thanq @NimerFarahty,

Answer (score 0):

Update from [Github](https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm) by contributing developer

1. To existing react-native-fcm users react-native-firebase now can do
   what react-native-fcm can so it is a waste of effort to build the
   same thing in parallel.
2. react-native-fcm will still take PRs and bug fixes, but possibly no new feature developement any more.